# Visual Studio 2015 builds failing because pre-build event 'requires elevation'

Tags: visual-studio, cmd, msbuild, elevation, build-events

I have a very simple VS2015 solution with one project. The project does not have any source code, but it has a pre-build event defined. The pre-build event was originally invoking a batch file `pb.bat`, but I have since changed it to `REM pb.bat` so that it only executes the `REM` statement.

Every time I try building, I get the following error message:

```
Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1250,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "cmd.exe" could not be run. The requested operation requires elevation
```

I should note that UAC is disabled. This is driving me crazy! I have even tried reinstalling Visual Studio, in case the targets files or something else was corrupt with the installation, but the problem persists. If I run Visual Studio as an Administrator, the build works, but I don't want to have to run it like that forever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had completely forgotten about this! A couple of days ago I had configured `cmd.exe` to always run as an Administrator. This was done in the registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"="RUNASADMIN"
```

The problem went away as soon as I reverted the change. I am making a note of this, as I am bound to hit the same problem in the future.

Comment: Thanks! I have to wait until tomorrow before I can mark this as the answer.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.